# Split a matrix into two by row using an odd number of rows

Tags: r

I want to extract/split a matrix by an odd number. Specifically, I want the first 15 rows then the next 14 rows to be separated. I.E.

```
submatrix_15 <- <rows 1-14, rows 30-44, etc>
submatrix_14 <- <rows 15-29, rows 45-59, etc>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
x <- matrix(rep(1:100, each=10), nrow=100, ncol=10, byrow=TRUE)
x

submatrix_15 <- x[which(seq(nrow(x)) %/% 15 %% 2 == 0),]
submatrix_14 <- x[which(seq(nrow(x)) %/% 15 %% 2 == 1),]

submatrix_15
submatrix_14
```

The `%/%`operator returns the quotient of a division, while `%%` returns the remainder. Thus the first operation returns groups of rows as specified, while the second returns whether these groups are odd (equaling 1) or even (equaling 0). Finally, the `which` function returns `TRUE`and `FALSE` values matching either 1's or 0's.

Answer (score 0):

Something like ...

```
x <- matrix(1:200, ncol=2)
x <- as.data.frame(suppressWarnings(cbind(x, c(rep(1,14), rep(2,15)))))
split(x[,-3], list(x[,3])
```

... will give you a list with two components (1: 1-14, 30-44  etc; 2: 15-29, 45-59 etc)